# Sync android framework code and build with custom changes

Tags: android, git, build, frameworks

I'm a Java developer and now exploring android..   I've learnt developing Apps but want to customize the framework and build it and deploy on my phone..   Web says a Linux machine is needed.  I installed Ubuntu virtual machine on my windows 7 Machine..

How do I now sync the code and carry development?

Answer (score -1):

**Installing stuff and building android from source code**

1. Installing the repo client.

[image: Installing the repo]

2. Time to create a working directory so you can put the downloaded code there . Now If you know the branch/version of android you want to download you can initialize the `repo` and start downloading.

[image]

3. Follow the links below for more details on how to setup the repo (wrapper around git) and start downloading the source code.
   [image]
4. Finally when the source code download finishes , start building the source code .
   [image]

[image]

[image]

**Finally run it...**

```
emulator
```

**FYI :**

Make sure you have java (the version mentioned on the links) is in your system path.

Here are some resources to try building android from source code.

1. Android source code [page](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html)
2. I wrote something on it as well...Read it [here](http://cafebabe1991.blogspot.se/2013/10/digging-deep-inside-build.html)

Comment: I did sync the code android_5.1.0_r3 but it is still running..   The. repo file is 15.3gb and I dono how much is remaining..   Can someone help..